Issue with Discord Bot Anti-Link Feature: Links Not Being Deleted
**Problem Description:
I'm currently working on implementing an anti-link feature for my Discord bot using Discord.js and Firebase Realtime Database. The feature is supposed to delete any messages containing links within a server's channels. However, I'm encountering an issue where the bot fails to delete messages with links.
Issue Details:
The anti-link feature is designed to toggle on/off based on user commands (antilink on/off).
When the feature is enabled, the bot is expected to delete any messages containing links in real-time.
I've verified that the bot successfully retrieves the messages in the channel and correctly identifies messages with links.
However, despite identifying messages with links, the bot fails to delete them as intended.
Code Overview:
// antilink.js

const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const db = require('../db/db.js'); //firebase 

// Function to delete messages containing links
async function deleteMessagesWithLinks(channel) {
    try {
        const messages = await channel.messages.fetch(); // Fetch all messages in the channel
        messages.forEach(msg => {
            if (msg.content.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g)) { // Check if the message contains a link
                msg.delete()
                    .then(deletedMsg => console.log(`Deleted message: ${deletedMsg.content}`))
                    .catch(error => console.error('Error deleting message:', error));
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching or deleting messages:', error);
    }
}

// Command to toggle anti-link feature on/off and delete links
async function execute(message, args) {
    if (!message.guild) return message.reply('This command can only be used in a server.');

    const guildId = message.guild.id;

    try {
        if (args[0] === 'status') {
            // Check the current status of the anti-link feature
            const snapshot = await db.ref(`guilds/${guildId}/antilink/enabled`).once('value');
            const isEnabled = snapshot.val();

            // Send a message with the current status
            const statusMessage = isEnabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled';
            const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor('#00ff00') // Example color
                .setTitle(`Anti-link feature is ${statusMessage}`)
                .setDescription(`Anti-link feature is currently ${statusMessage}.`);
            return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
        }

        // Toggle anti-link feature on/off
        const snapshot = await db.ref(`guilds/${guildId}/antilink/enabled`).once('value');
        let isEnabled = snapshot.val();

        if (args[0] === 'on') {
            if (isEnabled) {
                return message.channel.send('Anti-link feature is already enabled.');
            }
            isEnabled = true;
        } else if (args[0] === 'off') {
            if (!isEnabled) {
                return message.channel.send('Anti-link feature is already disabled.');
            }
            isEnabled = false;
        } else {
            // If no argument is provided, display the current status
            const status = isEnabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled';
            return message.channel.send(`Anti-link feature is currently ${status}.`);
        }

        // Update the anti-link feature status in the database
        await db.ref(`guilds/${guildId}/antilink`).update({ enabled: isEnabled });

        // Send a confirmation message with status
        const statusMessage = isEnabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled';
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#00ff00') // Example color
            .setTitle(`Anti-link feature has been ${statusMessage}`)
            .setDescription(`Anti-link feature is now ${statusMessage}.`);
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

        // If anti-link feature is enabled, delete messages with links
        if (isEnabled) {
            await deleteMessagesWithLinks(message.channel);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error toggling anti-link feature:', error);
        message.channel.send('An error occurred while toggling anti-link feature. Please try again later.');
    }
}

// Export the command and the deleteMessagesWithLinks function in a single module.exports
module.exports = {
    name: 'antilink',
    description: 'Toggle anti-link feature on/off and delete links.',
    execute,
    deleteMessagesWithLinks
};

Below is a summary of the relevant code snippets:
The deleteMessagesWithLinks function is responsible for fetching messages in a channel and deleting those containing links.
The execute function handles toggling the anti-link feature on/off based on user commands.
Both functions are exported from the module and executed accordingly when the bot receives relevant commands.
Additional Context:
I've ensured that the bot has the necessary permissions (such as MANAGE_MESSAGES) to delete messages in the channel.
The Firebase Realtime Database is correctly configured, and the bot is able to retrieve and update data from it without any issues.
I'm seeking guidance on identifying the potential cause of this issue and implementing a solution to ensure that the bot successfully deletes messages containing links when the anti-link feature is enabled.
Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Note : version - discord.js v14

I cannot be 100% sure what is the cause of your problem without seeing the MessageCreate event file, but i think it's most likely due to the code structure in the MessageCreate event listener. The "deleteMessagesWithLinks" function won't trigger after the command execution, the best solution is to put this function at the top of your MessageCreate event.
It should look something like this
discord.client.on('MessageCreate', (msg) => {
  const guild = msg.guild;
  const channel = msg.channel;

  if (!msg.startsWith('prefix')) {
    // check here for the link in msg.content
  } else {
    // execute cmd
  }
}).setMaxListeners(0);


